# Compile project and include libraries using batch script

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

In `CMD` I compile project with including libraries

`java -cp app.jar;libs/*;. com.app.Main`

and it works, but I want create `BATCH` script, which do exactly the same. I create `test.bat` and put code like below:

```
@ECHO off

java -cp app.jar;libs/*;. com.app.Main

PAUSE
```

But when I run the `test.bat` the `CMD` was shown and there is information `"Error: Could not find or load main class com.app.Main".`

`BATCH` script is located at the same folder as `app.jar` and `libs` folder.

**What is wrong with this batch script?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[After Java 6, Classpaths could be built by using wildcard characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

You can create a directory named `classpath` and put your JARs inside it. Then you can create your `.bat` file like this:

```
@ECHO off
java -cp .;classpath/* com.app.Main
pause
```

You should have a structure like this:

```
com
`---app
    `---Main.java
classpath
`---your-crital-code-1.0.jar
compile.bat
```

---

I see that a lot of people are asking this question on StackOverflow, so here is a little tip for you guys.

I usually avoid using the `cd` command, as it may create some hassle. In windows, you can `Shift + Right Click` to open a command window in a particular directory.

I always prefer relative paths over absolutes, so that I don't get into hassle of managing long paths.

[Here](https://github.com/JExaples/quicklooks/tree/master/compile-bat-with-classpath) is a little program that deals with this kind of problem. You can always refer to and [contribute](https://github.com/JExaples) to it so that we can make good examples for Java beginners :)

Comment: This do not help. Return the same message "Error: Could not find or load main class com.app.Main" when running `.bat` file. com.app.Main is inside `app.jar`

Comment: Can I have a look at your directory structure and the batch file?

Comment: Folder `libs` which contain all libraries, `test.bat` and `app.jar` are at the same directory

Comment: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.app.Main` refers to a situation where the compiler is unable to find the class. Have you compiled your program? If yes, have you compiled it correctly?

Comment: In Windows `CMD` it works but in `BATCH` not. Maybe when I run `test.bat` it do not know where he is - do not now own location to find this folders which are in the same directory?

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to paths. Use relative paths. Avoid absolutes  and use them only when required. I just upload a quick example for you. Check it out [here](https://github.com/JExaples/quicklooks/tree/master/compile-bat-with-classpath)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122663/discussion-between-czarek-and-jay).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the characters on the compile line are significant to the batch interpreter; try putting the classpath in double quotes.

Comment: I try `java -cp "app.jar;libs/*;" "com.app.Main"` but do not work.

Comment: In your comment here, you don't have the period (".") in the classpath. I can't tell if that's the problem, because you don't even tell me what the error message is (assuming you got an error message). When asking for help here, assume we don't know anything about your computer, what you've typed, or what is displayed in response, and that we need that information exactly, not a summary of it.